# Crontab: invalid option -- '1' crontab: usage error: unrecognized option when typing crontab -1

Tags: cron

I am trying to use crontab on my digital ocean server. When I type `crontab -1` it gives me this error

```
crontab: invalid option -- '1'
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

when I type `crontab -i` it gives me this error

```
crontab: usage error: file name must be specified for replace
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

How can I fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you want `crontab -l` (the letter to the right of the `k`-key on qwerty-style keyboards)?

Comment: OH my god! I thought that was a '1' Thank you so much